DarkTable keyboardrc for LightRoom users
What is the best way to make DarkTable keyboard shortcuts to mirror LightRoom as much as possible?
Would I need to go thru all the functions and set the shortcuts manually or can anybody share a ready-made keyboard mapping file?
Or, perhaps, would you recommend forgetting the LighRoom shortcuts altogether and start afresh? (Although muscle memory is quite a thing for a long-time LR user)
